# Ruby and a Math Problem

Tags: ruby, math, e-commerce, subtotal

Let's say I have to have a cart with a subtotal of 1836.36.  I must achieve this exact amount by adding up several products from a list with a range of prices.

Say, I have a few products at 9.99, 29.99, 59.99 and I can add several of each to meet the desired subtotal. How would one approach this problem using Ruby?

I've thought of feeding the list of prices into a script and somehow getting the script to add until it reaches the subtotal and then spit out the prices required to reach the subtotal... just not sure how to approach it.

Any suggestions are welcome and thanks in advance.  Looking forward to ideas.

Comment: Do all the prices end in .99? That would make it easy to find out how many items there might be.

Comment: Are you looking for help with the code to accomplish this, or the mathematical algorithm?

Comment: Assuming there is a definite solution with the values provided, then this is a knapsack problem.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem  Which can be solved mathematically.

Comment: Agreed with Gazler above, and you probably will want to use the dynamic programming solution approach described there. That's generally best for modest data set sizes.

Comment: Interesting reading related to this:
http://www.rubyquiz.com/quiz154.html

Comment: The knapsack problem is, unfortunately, NP-Complete, so it is unlikely that you can do much better than trial and error.

Comment: From the linked Wikipedia page, it is NP-Complete, but also pseudo-polynomial. This basically means that the runtime is polynomial in the numeric value of the subtotal (here 1836.36). NP-Completeness comes from the fact that the subtotal may grow exponentially with the length of the input, which may not be a problem in practice. The dynamic programming solution is quite nice, take a look at the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Definitely looking at the Knapsack problem as a potential solution for this problem.  Thanks Gazler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

9.99*x + 29.99*y + 59.99*z = 1836.36

brute force iterate through all the permutations of x,y,z within a range of integers

For example:

```
(0..9).each do |x|
  (0..9).each do |y|
    (0..9).each do |z|
       puts "x #{x} y #{y} z #{z}" if (x * 9.99 + y * 29.99 + z * 59.99 == 1836.36)
    end
  end
end
```

discard any answer whose sum is not 1835.36.

Something like that... haven't tested it.  You could probably tweak and optimize it to ignore cases that would certainly fail to pass.

Comment: I guess this would work for a small fixed number of products, yet I think that instead of using 9 for all three cases they should be calculated as `ceil(total_price/article_price)` to account for the case when there are 0 of the other two items.

Comment: I'll check this solution out as well.  Not sure it will work in practice very well.  I have a very large list of product prices to deal with.